# I'm having trouble rooting my Samsung J320P with heimdall

Tags: rooting, heimdall

I can't download the pit. i connected to the device with adb. i'll try downloading the pit file and heimdall will tell me

```
Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Downloading device's PIT file...
ERROR: Failed to send request to end PIT file transfer!
ERROR: Failed to download PIT file!
ERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
Releasing device interface...


Ending session...
```

Comment: Why do you have to partition? What rooting method are you attempting to use?

Comment: I am using TWRP to root

Comment: Did you follow the rooting guide as described? I don't think you need repartitioning, just load the .tar file.

Comment: when i load the package it tells me "firmware.xml was missing from the package" with a big red X. when i just do flash directly from the recovery image it repartitions anyways

Answer (score 0):

Rooting doesn't need you repartitioning the phone. Just flash a custom recovery and then flash the rooting files through that recovery.

I'd suggest you to install TWRP recovery.  There is a complete guide on how to flash the recovery and rooting zip files [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/recovery-teamwin-recovery-project-3-0-2-t3356616). Just follow CAREFULLY everything, step by step. (The guide is for Odin, I think it will work for Heimdall as well).

Comment: when i load the package it tells me "firmware.xml was missing from the package" with a big red X. when i just do flash directly from the recovery image it repartitions anyways.

Comment: How do toi load it? You're supposed to flash with à computer! Install Odin or Heimdall